# How to use load_file with Azure Database for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to load image data into a row column on Azure database for MySQL.  This is the SQL statement I am trying to run through MySQL Workbench...

```
insert into pm1.c1 (id,source,image) values ('1','a',load_file('/usr/csuser/clouddrive/a.jpg'));
```

It produces a good result but the image column is null.  The challenge is to give access to the file from the server instance.  I found a blog post that seemed to put me on the right track...

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-mysql/backup-azure-database-for-mysql-to-a-blob-storage/ba-p/803830

This involves running the cloud shell that creates blob storage.  I uploaded the a.jpg image to the fileshare.  Of course not accessible from the MySQL server, hence the null result.

So apparently I need some type of UNC syntax to reference the file in the load_file call.  Cannot figure out what that might be.  Azure store connect strings want you to mount a volume on the server, but as far as I can tell there is no way to connect to the host running the MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that load_file is fundamentally incompatible with Azure Database for MySQL.  There is nothing in the documentation about this incompatibility.

The reason I know it is incompatible is that it is specifically listed as incompatible in the docs for Google Cloud SQL for MySQL: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features

I've seen this time and again...if one cloud server has something then the others will scramble to get it.  Conversely if something is unsupported on one cloud then you can be certain that it is unsupported on the others.

load_file() is apparently seen as a security hole.  So the way to use load_file() is that you need to have a local database on which load_file is run and then export the data to a flat file and then import it into Azure Database for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL document [load_file()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) :

Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this function:

1. The file must be located on the server host, you must specify the
   full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE privilege.
2. The file must be readable by the server and its size less than
   `max_allowed_packet` bytes.
3. If the `secure_file_priv` system variable is set to a nonempty
   directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that
   directory. (Prior to MySQL 8.0.17, the file must be readable by all,
   not just readable by the server.)

If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns NULL.

Other more details:

MySQL LOAD_FILE fucntion is several conditions to be met to be executed successfully.

- File which you are trying to load must be present in the same host
  where MySQL server is running. For example, if your MySQL server is
  installed on example.com, file must be present on example.com only.
- Full path name of the file must be specified. So, if your file is
  located within a user's home directory, assuming username w3r, you
  must specify '/home/w3r/somefile.txt'
- User who is executing the command must have FILE privilege. You may
  grant FILE privilege to a user with following "GRANT FILE on dbname.*
  TO user@localhost".
- File in question must be readable by all. If you are trying to load a
  file which is not present on the users home directory hieararchy,
  make sure you have read permission on the file.
- MySQL Server has a max_allowed_packet variable. File in question must
  not exceed value specified in that variable. You may check value of
  max_allowed_packet with 'show variables like
  '%max_allowed_packet%';'; you must have MySQL root privilege for
  executing this command. You change the value of max_allowed_packet in
  your MySQL configuration file. Open your my.ini or my.cnf file, find
  the line max_allowed_packet=some_value and change the value to your
  desired one, for example if you want to set the valle to say 50MB,
  write 50MB.
- MySQL has a secure_file_priv variable. If value of that variable is
  set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be
  located in that directory. You may find the secure_file_priv variable
  and its value and may chnage it in your MySQL configuration file.

Reference: [MySQL LOAD_FILE() function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-load_file-function.php) and [How the LOAD_FILE() Function Works in MySQL](https://database.guide/how-the-load_file-function-works-in-mysql/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't help at all.  This is Azure Database for MySQL.  There is no way that I can figure out logon to the server host.  You can't even figure out what the server host is.  So none of you many pieces of advice will work.  They all rely on being able to access the server host.